# How to construct IBOutlet names in code in order to change them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, iboutlet

Let's say I've got several UILabels which have been set up in IB and connected to IBOulets in code (label1, label2, label3, label4)

How would I create these variable names within code, so that I could change the text of each one in a loop, where the labels are taken from a NSArray.

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
labelArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"this", @"array", @"has", @"a", @"random", @"amount", @"of", @"items", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) 
{
    // labelx is the constructed name of the IBOutlet
    lablex.text = [labelArray objectAtIndex:i];

}
```

How do I construct 'labelx' above? Could this be done using Blocks?

Comment: the lableArray has a dynamic size right? And you want to map every element in that array to a UILabel? But you don't have a dynamic amount of labels? 
If you really want this you could eventually use - (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to initialize the array at some place, using

```
labelArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"this", @"array", @"has", nil];
uiLabelArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:label1,label2,label3,nil];
```

then

```
for (int i = 0; i < [uiLabelArray count]; i++) 
{
    [uiLabelArray objectAtIndex:i].text = [labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: I already have a labelArray. The issue is turning that array into text in the UILabels within a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use key value coding (KVC). It would look something like:

`[[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d", i]] setText:[labelArray objectAtIndex:i]];`

More info can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html)

Comment: Ewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.